# In Kafka, How could I set min.insync.replicas=1 to __consumer_offsets_ topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have one Kafka broker.

My server.properties is as follows:

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
default.replication.factor=3
min.insync.replicas=3
```

And I created a topic just for test:

```
sh kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --create replication-factor 1 --config min.insync.replicas=1
```

The topic is created well. It describes as follows:

```
Topic: test PartitionCount: 8 ReplicationFactor: 1 Configs: min.insync.replicas=1, segment.bytes=10...
Topic: test Partition: 0 Leader: 1 Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
....
```

When my console consumer starts working, the following error occurs:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotEnoughReplicasException: The size of the current ISR Set(1) is insufficient to satisfy the min.isr requirement of 3 for partition __ consumer_offsets-1
```

As I understand, I set the min.insync.replicas to 1, but it affects only data topics, not _*consumer_offsets* topics. So _*consumer_offsets* still needs 3 replicas as my server.properties has min.insync.replicase=3 setting.

Is my understanding correct?? if so, is there a way to set __consumer_offsets topics' min.insync.replicas in command line topic creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Is my understanding correct??"

Yes, your understanding is correct. The configuration [min.insync.replicas](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#min.insync.replicas) can be set when creating a topic. If you do not specify this configuration it will be set based on the broker-wide configuration `min.insync.replicas` that is provided in the `server.properties`.

> "if so, is there a way to set __consumer_offsets topics' min.insync.replicas in command line topic creation?"

As the topic `__consumer_offsets` is an internal topic and it will be created automatically, the broker-wide defaults are being used. In your case you would need to change the configuration in your *server.properties* file:

```
min.insync.replicas=1
```

As I understand, you only have *one* broker in your cluster. So having default setting of `3` for the configurations `offsets.topic.replication.factor`, `default.replication.factor`, and `min.insync.replicas` will cause issues (like you have seen) for topics that rely on those broker-wide settings.

---

Please do **not** change these setting on a production cluster without really knowing the impacts. It will have an impact on the durability of your data and your ConsumerGroups and there is a good reason why the defaults are set to `3`.

Answer (score -3):

if your min isr configuration not taking effect, here is the solution:

*Note: operation below will remove all the kafka data, this solution is purely for changing the isr settings of internal topics that have already been created, you should never do it when this data cleanup operation doesn't fit into your scenario*

every time you want to change replica factor and min isr, don't forgot to clear the internal topics first:

```
rm -rf kafka/kafka-logs/*
rm -rf kafka/logs/*
rm -rf zookeeper/zkdata/version-2/* 
rm -rf zookeeper/logs/version-2/*
```

you can confirm whether your config working by describe all the topics including the internal topics:

```
topics=(`./kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper $ZK_SERVER | grep -v grep  | awk '{print $1}'`)                                                                                         
for topic in ${topics[@]}
do
./kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server $BOOTS_STRAP_SERVER --topic $topic
done
```

Comment: Very dangerous suggestion that might cause data loss

Comment: it's nothing related to 'dangerous', this is the only way to change min isr of the internal topics that already have been created, of course, for production you should always know what you're doing